# C++ map<K,T> Initialization

Tags: c++, stl, dictionary, variable-assignment

I'm reading "Ivor Horton's Beginning Programming Visual C++ 2010", and I'm at Chapter 10-The Standard Template Library. My problem is with the map container `map<Person, string> mapname`. The book showed me a lot of ways of adding elements to it, such as with the `pair<K, T>` and using the `make_pair()` function later, and `mapname.insert(pair)`. But suddenly he introduced an element adding technique used in the following code:

```
int main()
{
    std::map<string, int> words
    cout << "Enter some text and press Enter followed by Ctrl+Z then Enter to end:"
        << endl << endl;

    std::istream_iterator<string> begin(cin);
    std::istream_iterator<string> end;

    while(being != end)   // iterate over words in the stream
        //PROBLEM WITH THIS LINE:
        words[*begin++]++;  // Increment and store a word count

    //there are still more but irrelevant to this question)
}
```

The indicated line is my problem. I understand that `words` is the map, but I've never seen such initialization. And what's going on in that thing with its increment. I believe Ivor Horton failed to elaborate this further, or at least he should've given introductions big enough not to suprise noobs like me.

Comment: You have a missing `;` after `words`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You have such a map:

```
sts::map<std::string, int> m;
```

The access operator `[key]` gives you a reference to the element stored with that key, or inserts one if it doesn't exist. So for an empty map, this

```
m["hello"];
```

inserts an entry in the map, with key "Hello" and value 0. It also returns a reference to the value. So you can increment it directly:

```
m["Bye"]++;
```

would insert a value 0 under key "Bye" and increment it by one, or increment an existing value by 1.

As for the stuff happening inside the `[]` operator,

```
*begin++
```

is a means to incrementing the `istream_iterator` and dereferencing the value before the increment:

```
begin++;
```

increments `begin` and returns the value before the increment

```
*someIterator
```

dereferences the iterator.

Comment: Thank you so much, the step by step instructions really nailed it. I hope the author of the book explained it that way.

Comment: @JoeyArnoldAndres If this answer was the solution to your problem (or the best from multiple correct solutions), [accepting](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/162011) is the correct response.

Answer (score 1):

He is doing two things at once, and generally being more clever than he needs to be.

1. He is getting the value the iterator points to, and then incrementing the iterator. So, interpret `*begin++` as `*(begin++)`. Note that it's a postincrement, though, so the increment happens AFTER the dereference.
2. He is incrementing the value for the given key in your map. When you dereference the iterator, you get a string. This string is used as the key for the `words` map, whose value is incremented.

Spread over more lines, it looks like this:

```
std::string x = *begin;
begin++;
words[x] += 1;
```